# Azure Functions Service Bus Trigger: getting Serialization exception when trying to bind to custom class

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-functions

I'm creating an Azure Function with Service Bus trigger and trying to bind the incoming message to a custom class of mine:

```
public class InputMessage
{
    public string EntityId { get; set; }
}

public static string Run(InputMessage message, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus trigger function processed message: {message}");
}
```

My message is JSON, e.g.

```
{ "EntityId": "1234" }
```

Unfortunately, the binding fails at runtime with the following message:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.ServiceBusTriggerCSharp1.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: One or more errors occurred. Exception
>   binding parameter 'message'. System.Runtime.Serialization: Expecting
>   element 'Submission_x0023_0.InputMessage' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/'.. Encountered 'Element' 
>   with name 'string', namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'. .

It looks like the runtime tries to deserialize the message with `DataContractSerializer`. How do I switch the deserialization to JSON?

Answer (score 10):

`BrokeredMessage` which comes to the function must have `ContentType` property explicitly set to `application/json`. If it's not specified, the default `DataContractSerializer` will be assumed. So, do this when *sending* the message:

```
var message = new BrokeredMessage(body)
{
    ContentType = "application/json"
};
```

See [ServiceBus Serialization Scenarios](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/ServiceBus-Serialization-Scenarios) for details.

Comment: Using a C# Precompiled function I was having issues with serialization of out-bound parameters as an object (POCO). The objects where getting converted to a literal string value of "null". It was still triggering ServiceBusTrigger Azure Functions with null objects. Setting the BrokeredMessage out parameter to null or Serializing them as a BrokeredMessage setting ContentType solved it for me. Thank you so much!